# Декодирование ссылки

Tags: jquery

Есть код, которым нужно взять ссылку, поделить её и использовать.
Всё работает нормально, но не с кириллицей.
Если вводить ссылку в адресную строку самостоятельно - то всё работает прекрасно, но если вставить куда-то на сайт и перейти - то кириллица перекодирована.

Как вылечить данный недуг?

```
var linkUrl = location.href; // допустим http://site.ru/поиск?=запрос
var linkUrl = linkUrl.split('?=');
var linkUrl = linkUrl[1]; //запрос
```

Пробовал через `decodeURI();`, но в консоль выводится ошибка
`URIError: malformed URI sequence`..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Пробовал через `decodeURI`

А надо через `decodeURIComponent`

Comment: Тоже пробовал.. Аналогичная ситуация. И `var linkUrl = decodeURIComponent(location.href)` пробовал, и `var linkUrl = decodeURIComponent(linkUrl[1]);` - всё равно ошибка..